# Regular expressions - turn it around

Tags: php, regex

I'm having troubles with my regex. I managed to do the opposite of what i was looking for, but i need help to turn it around.

It supposed to do the following:

1. remove all words between all "bunny ears"
2. remove all words starting with -before the word (Not in-between the words)

The regex below somewhat does this, but the opposite! i need help to turn it around. I have looked through numerous tutorials and online guides but i cannot find any answer to this.

([\"].+?[\"])|([-][a-öA-Ö0-9]+)

Thank you!

Sorry all, i forgot to include what i expect.

if i test the regex on this text:
-item first search string -item2 -item3 "important"

I expect the Regex to match the following words only!

first
search
string

Comment: Can you provide example string and desired result?

Comment: Yes, so sorry! Like:
-item first search string -item2 -item3 "important"

Should result in: 
first 
search 
string

Comment: Please update (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53894999/edit) the question with samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

```
$str = ' -item first search string -item2 -item3 "important"';
preg_match_all('/(?<!["-])\b\w+\b(?!")/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => first
            [1] => search
            [2] => string
        )

)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!["-])   # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't quote or dash before
\b\w+\b     # 1 or more word characters, surrounded with word boundary
(?!")       # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't quote after
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Toto for the explanation also! The reason we are all here is to learn, and your answer was straight forward, and i would like to thank you for your time to help out, and also help to teach me a little bit more about this!

Answer (score 1):

For php:

```
<?php
$actual = '-item first search string -item2 -item3 "important"';

$expect = preg_replace(
    '/(\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\")|(\B-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/',
    '',
    $actual
);

echo $expect;
```

```js
const actual = '-item first search string -item2 -item3 "important"';

const expect = actual
  .replace(/\B-[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '')
  .replace(/"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\"/, '');

const expect2 = actual.replace(/(\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\")|(\B-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, '');
  
console.log(expect);
console.log(expect2);
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but it is actually supposed to do the opposite, instead of matching -item and -item2 -item3 - it should be matching :

first
search
string